# Getting different result each time I run a linear regression using scikit

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Hi I have a linear regression model that i am trying to optimise. I am optimising the span of an exponential moving average and the number of lagged variables that I use in the regression.

However I keep finding that the results and the calculated mse keep coming up with different final results. No idea why can anyone help?

Process after starting loop:
1. Create new dataframe with three variables
2. Remove nil values
3. Create ewma's for each variable
4. Create lags for each variable
5. Drop NA's
6. Create X,y
7. Regress and save ema span and lag number if better MSE
8. start loop with next values

I know that this could be a question for cross validated but since it could be a programmatic I have posted here:

```
bestema = 0
bestlag = 0
mse = 1000000

for e in range(2, 30):
    for lags in range(1, 20):
        df2 = df[['diffbn','diffbl','diffbz']]
        df2 = df2[(df2 != 0).all(1)]        
        df2['emabn'] = pd.ewma(df2.diffbn, span=e)
        df2['emabl'] = pd.ewma(df2.diffbl, span=e)
        df2['emabz'] = pd.ewma(df2.diffbz, span=e)
        for i in range(0,lags):
            df2["lagbn%s" % str(i+1)] = df2["emabn"].shift(i+1)
            df2["lagbz%s" % str(i+1)] = df2["emabz"].shift(i+1)
            df2["lagbl%s" % str(i+1)] = df2["emabl"].shift(i+1)
        df2 = df2.dropna()
        b = list(df2)
            #print(a)
        b.remove('diffbl')
        b.remove('emabn')
        b.remove('emabz')
        b.remove('emabl')
        b.remove('diffbn')
        b.remove('diffbz')
        X = df2[b]
        y = df2["diffbl"]
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
        #print(X_train.shape)
        regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
        regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
        if(mean_squared_error(y_test,regr.predict(X_test)) < mse):
            mse = mean_squared_error(y_test,regr.predict(X_test) ** 2)
            #mse = mean_squared_error(y_test,regr.predict(X_test))
            bestema = e
            bestlag = lags
            print(regr.coef_)
            print(bestema)
            print(bestlag)
            print(mse)
```

Comment: Is `train_test_split` the function from sklearn (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html)? This is random, so logical you get different results each time. You can pass a `random_state` keyword to have it the same each time.

Comment: ahh that explains it, I need to do this myself then and tak the first 70% as train then test on the next 30%

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `train_test_split` function from sklearn (see docs: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html) is random, so it is logical you get different results each time.
You can pass an argument to the `random_state` keyword to have it the same each time.